# number of permutation where the numbers are totally seperated

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given the word $S,T,P,M,9,5,4,3$, find the number of permutations where the numbers are totally separated.

First I use $4p4 \times 4p4$, where $4p4 = 24$. Then I considered the arrangements of numbers and letters.
$9,S,5,T,4,P,3,M$
$9,ST,5,P,4,M,3$
$9,S,5,TP,4,M,3$
$9,S,5,T,4,PM,3$
$S,9,T,5,P,4,M,3$
After including the conditions above I found out $4p4 \times 4p4 \times 5$ which is $24 \times 24 \times 5 =2880$. But the answer should be $8640$. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: The question is incomprehensible.  Please write out your question clearly and your answer with more detail.  Is the question the number of ways to arrange four letters and four numbers so that no two numbers are next to each other?

Comment: yeah the numbers need to be totally separated

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Your question would be clearer if you said find the number of permutations that can be formed using all the characters $S, P, T, M, 9, 5, 4, 3$ in which the numbers are totally separated.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you.  There are five orders of numbers and letters that have no numbers next to each other, then $4!$ ways to order the numbers and $4!$ ways to order the letters.

Comment: so the answer given should be wrong right?

Comment: That is what I said.